# Creating directories with correct permissions for Laravel

Tags: permissions

I’m a developer. A few days ago I started using Laravel on Ubuntu. When I use the terminal to create a new directory it appears with a padlock on it. Even logged in as root I have to give it permission with `chmod`.

How can I create directories with all permissions for all kind of users?

Comment: What is the exact terminal command that you are using? what is the output of the `umask` command?

Comment: Actually I’m using laravel, so every time I create a new migration or send files from a form this happens

Comment: using `chmod g+s /var/www/app_root_dir`  can be usesfull in few cases (during developement) - that way every new file and dir created in `/var/www/app_root_dir` would inherit group of `app_root_dir` (ie www-data). When you decide to deploy it as production you should defenitley follow laravels documentation recommendations.

Answer (score 15):

When using `laravel` on Ubuntu you want to set it up in the following ways that will ensure you don't use or need root access for the created files.

1. Location of created projects should be in `/var/www/html` folder but can be anywhere.
2. Install composer and set that up globally so you can install `laravel` globally with it.
3. The permissions in `/var/www/html` need to be set up such that you don't need `root` privileges to operate on files there as it is in your case.

## Install Composer:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Check Install:

```
composer -V
```

## Install laravel using composer:

```
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```

Check install:

```
laravel -V
```

## Setup folder permissions for laravel:

1. Temporary setup in `/var/www/html`:

   - Add self to group `www-data`:

     ```
     sudo usermod -a -G www-data $USER
     ```
   - Change ownership of laravel folder:

     ```
     sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www/html/project
     ```
   - Tip: to setup laravel storage:

     ```
     sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/project/storage
     ```
2. Permanent solution:

   - Make default ownership of folders in `/var/www/html` `$USER:www-data`, so any new creation will assume the permissions of your user and the group www-data

     ```
     sudo setfacl -d -R -m u:$USER:rwx,g:www-data:rwx,o:rx /var/www/html
     ```

Now simply add any user to the `www-data` group to have them have `rwx` access to any created laravel project in `/var/www/html`. **A reboot will be required**.

## Usage:

```
laravel new /var/www/html/new-project
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mkdir -m a=rwx myDir
```

or

```
mkdir --mode=a=rwx myDir
```

Run `mkdir --help` for more info.