# unable to read/write to newly created files linux

Tags: permissions, user-management

I have setup laravel on a linux server and my apache is owned by root and www is owned by www-data and any new file created is owned by root user in the storage dir here is the screenshot of [permissions](http://prntscr.com/lylaq5) for all directories inside /var/www/website/

And [these](http://prntscr.com/lylb87) are the permissions inside storage/logs dir. The newly created file is owned by the root user. Now, web server is unable to open this file for writing which causes errors on the website. I am not sure if this happens whent the root owns the file or when. But I kept ignoring this and kept applying a temporary fix by using the commands

`sudo chmod -R 775 storage` or `sudo chown www-data:www-data storage`

I want to fix this error once and for all. For reference [these](http://prntscr.com/lylcs1) 
are the permissions inside /etc/ dir

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating directories with correct permissions for Laravel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/983922/creating-directories-with-correct-permissions-for-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

ACL let's you add additional user permissions - where for example, the file could be owned by www-data but other users can have r/w permission on it. To set this up:

Install acl (apt install acl). Then in your fstab file, add acl as an option. For example:

```
/dev/sda / ext3 noatime,errors=remount-ro,acl 0 1
```

Then remount:

```
mount -a
```

Change the ownership of all the files backed to www-data if you've changed them. Set the default "acls" for any files that will later be created:

```
setfacl -dm u:myname:rwx /var/www
```

... and set the acls on already existing files:

```
setfacl -m u:myname:rw
```

... and directories

```
setfacl -m u:myname:rwx
```

Comment: adding user root to the www-data group wont solve the problem?

Comment: root can already change any file so adding root to another group won't help. But you can setfacl -m u:www-data:rw on those files - and change the default acl on the log directory so www-data can access the new log files.

Comment: yeah, but in my case as you can see the log file owned by root doesnt have appropriate permissions http://prntscr.com/lym6lp